# why javascript alert function is not working?

Tags: javascript

```
scoops=5;
      while(scoops<6){
          alart ("ice creame is getting low");
      }
      console.log("life without icecream is not same");
```

when I want to run it show me reference error. the alert is not defined. can you tell why does this happen?

Comment: You wrote `alart`, not `alert`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Replace `alart(...)` by `alert(...)`

Comment: And note that that loop will run forever since you never alter `scoops`.

Answer (score -1):

You spelled it wrong. Simply replace `alart` to `alert`. And always look over your code so you avoid things like this.